# Add Header and Footer to Word Document from ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, ms-word

Is there any way to add Header and Footer Info to Word. I am currently writing HTML contents to word file using ASP.Net.

Comment: What technologies are you using? You can write direct to Word 2007+ (.docx) as it's basically just a zip file with XML in it (in an awful and poorly documented format, but never mind). If you're using   the older binary format then it all depends on which 3rd-party tool you're using to write to document.

Comment: I am working on ASP.Net, Currently I dont have any third party tool

Comment: Are you writing a .doc or a .docx?

Answer (score 1):

Code below can generate the MS Word document without using HTML format -

```
object oTrue = true;
object oFalse = false;
object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object novalue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
object fileName = "normal.dot";
object newTemplate = false;
object docType = 0;
object isVisible = true;

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass questionClient = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document questionDoc = questionClient.Documents.Add(ref fileName, ref newTemplate, ref docType, ref isVisible);
questionDoc.Activate();

//adding header
string logoPath = Server.MapPath("~//photos//logica_logo_black.JPG");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape logoCustom = null;
questionClient.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageHeader;
logoCustom = questionClient.Selection.HeaderFooter.Shapes.AddPicture(logoPath, ref oFalse, ref oTrue, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
logoCustom.Select(ref oMissing);
logoCustom.Name = "CustomLogo";
logoCustom.Left = -47;
logoCustom.Top = -19;

//adding footer
questionClient.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageFooter;
questionClient.ActiveWindow.Selection.Font.Name = "Verdana";
questionClient.ActiveWindow.Selection.Font.Size = 8;
Object CurrentPage = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage;
questionClient.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeText("For Logica Internal Use Only");
questionClient.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeText("                                             ");
questionClient.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeText("Page ");
questionClient.ActiveWindow.Selection.Fields.Add(questionClient.Selection.Range, ref CurrentPage, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
questionClient.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeText("                                                     ");
questionClient.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeText(DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

//saving and closing the document
questionClient.Documents.Save(ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
questionClient.Quit(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```